How can I migrate everything on one LightSail instance to a new instance with identical specs?
My old instance is IPv4 and I want to migrate the application and files on it to a new IPv6 only instance, other than that the server specs are identical including operating system (Amazon Linux).
Is there an easier way to duplicate what is currently running other than reinstalling everything on the new instance?

A warning for IPv6 only - some things break, even if you use CloudFlare so your users can access the server with IPv4 or IPv6. For example, Wordpress updates cannot be retrieved over IPv6. Other software may have issues as well.

AWS has NAT64 DNS64 for accessing legacy IP only internet hosts.  If IPv4 hosts need to access this instance, skip the migration to v6 only, or add a IPv4 load balancer in front.

Create a new IPv6 only instance from a backup snapshot of your old one.
You also should document, ideally automate, how to rebuild a new instance from scratch. Operating system template, install software, restore data. Probably more steps then restore from a backup image, but reinstalling makes more recovery or upgrade use cases possible.
Enjoy modern IP.
